# Showing Unitary operator in $L^2(\mathbb C)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lie-groups

I'm studying Lie group and functional analysis.

In $L^2(\mathbb{C})$, with respect to the measure ${(1+|z|^2)^w} dxdy$ which $x,y$ are real, imaginary part.

Let, $A : L^2(\mathbb{C}) \to L^2(\mathbb{C})$ be an operator such that $ad-bc= 1$, ($a,b,c,d\in \mathbb C$) and

$$Af(z) = |-bz + d|^{-2 - w} f\left(\frac{az-c}{-bz + d}\right)$$

Then, $A$ is unitary operator under $0<w<2$,

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_\mathbb{C}\int_\mathbb{C}\frac{f(z)\overline{g(\zeta)}dzd\zeta}{|z-\zeta|^{2-w}}$$

Firstly, I cannot prove the surjectiveness of $A$, but I think this prove might use some kinds of linear fractional transformation.

Second, I tried below formula, but I got some different results.

\begin{align*}
\langle f, g \rangle &= \int_\mathbb{C}\int_\mathbb{C}\frac{f(z)\overline{g(\zeta)}dzd\zeta}{|z-\zeta|^{2-w}}
\\
&=\int_\mathbb{C}\int_\mathbb{C}\frac{f(\frac{az-c}{-bz + d})\overline{g(\frac{a\zeta-c}{-b\zeta + d})}d\left(\frac{az-c}{-bz + d}\right)d\left(\frac{a\zeta-c}{-b\zeta + d}\right)}{|\frac{az-c}{-bz + d}-\frac{a\zeta-c}{-b\zeta + d}|^{2-w}}
\\
&= \int_\mathbb{C}\int_\mathbb{C}\frac{f(\frac{az-c}{-bz + d})\overline{g(\frac{a\zeta-c}{-b\zeta + d})}\frac{1}{|-bz + d|^2}dz\frac{1}{|-b\zeta + d|^2}d\zeta}{|\frac{z-\zeta}{(-bz + d)(-b\zeta + d)}|^{2-w}}
\\
&= \int_\mathbb{C}\int_\mathbb{C}\frac{f(\frac{az-c}{-bz + d})\overline{g(\frac{a\zeta-c}{-b\zeta + d})}|-bz + d|^{-w}|-b\zeta + d|^{-w}dzd\zeta}{|z-\zeta|^{2-w}}
\\&\neq \langle Af, Ag\rangle
\end{align*}

What's wrong with my calculation. Thank you.

In fact, this is concerend with Knapp, Representation theory of semisimple groups Page 34 (complementary series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is when you are doing the coordinate transform, the Möbius transform changes the volume element $dxdy$ to
$$\dfrac1{|-bz+d|^4} dxdy$$
so the exponent is a "$4$" not a "$2$".

This means that your $|-bz+d|^{-w}$ type expressions should be $|-bz+d|^{-2-w}$ in the final expression. As a consequence you find that $A$ does preserve the inner product.

To see bijectivity let $B$ be map corresponding to $\begin{pmatrix}d & -b\\ -c &a \end{pmatrix}$, ie the inverse Möbius transform corresponding to $A$. You may check that $AB = BA = \Bbb1$ by evaluating on an arbitrary function and looking at the equation pointwise. Remember that the $|-bz+d|^{-2-w}$ term must change to (for $BA(f)$):

$$\left|-b \left(\frac{dz+c}{bz+a}\right)+d\right|^{-2-w}\cdot|bz+a|^{-2-w}= |z\cdot (bd-db)+-bc+da|^{-2-w}=1$$

Whats left is to check that the map is well defined, which I'll leave to you.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!